# Java click listener issue

Tags: java, element, jlist

I create a `JList` in Java and I add some elements to it. When I click on an element a frame opens. But it opens up to the number of elements. İ would like to open only one frame.

Code:

```
model = new DefaultlistModel(); 

list = new JList(arkadasmodel); 
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
list.setBounds(30, 30, 120, 325); 
mesaj.add(list); 

if(sayi != 0) { 
  model.addElement(rs8.getString("abcdef")); 
 } 

list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter () { 
 public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent denemeacte){ 

    JFrame mesaj2 = new JFrame (debtndgr);
    mesaj2.setSize(300, 475);
    mesaj2.setVisible(true);

 } 
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify "it opens up to the number of element"? Where is the code to open the frame?

Comment: According to your code, nothing will happen, as the MouseListener#mouseClicked method doesn't actually contain any code.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy hi i changed question. I added codes.

Comment: @jhamon hi for example there are 3 element in the list so 3 frame open. i added codes

Comment: @ScriptKiddy help please

Comment: @jhamon help please